# scroll to certain div using url hashtag

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a vue Component it contains replies from users.

So when the user reply on a comment the op gets notification for the reply and the noti has URL with the comment id like : `url.com/post#c-900` .

if the user clicks on the link I'm trying to scroll to the comment when the user clicks on the link .

I tried to use this Jquery snippet in my blade view that i found in an answer :

```
 $(function() {
      // get hash value
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      // now scroll to element with that id
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top });
    });
```

the reply div :

```
  :id="'c-'+reply.id"
```

how i can handle this ? since the component is not rendered immediately when the page loads .

I Cant figure this out .

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component is not rendered immediately, I can think of two options:

1. If you have access to the function which loads the component, add `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top });` into the callback function which is called when the component is loaded.
2. If you don't have access, you can try polling for the element's existence in the DOM.

```js
var hash, timeout = 0, poll = window.setInterval(function() {
  hash = $(window.location.hash);

  if (hash.length) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: hash.offset().top });
    window.clearInterval(poll);

  } else if (timeout++ > 100) { // cancel the interval after 100 attempts (== 10s)
    window.clearInterval(poll);
  }
}, 100);
```

In the event someone clicks another link, you're going to want to clear the current polling function with `clearInterval(poll)` before setting a new one.

Comment: humm ok that works but if i scroll down and then scroll up > refresh the page it will scroll to the div and after the page is loaded will return to top

Answer (score 0):

You can to create a ref for your div [like this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/) in the reply component. Let's say the name of your ref is "yourdiv". Then in the "mounted" hook you can do something like this:

```
const hash = window.location.hash
if(hash === reply.id) {
    const distanceFromTop = this.$refs.yourdiv.getBoundingClientRect().top
    window.scrollTo({
      top: distanceFromTop,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    })
}
```

[How to use refs to access your application DOM in Vue.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/)

Comment: I'm not using vue-router